# Transfer data of Microsoft Project Server to Sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, project-server

I like to transfer data of Microsoft Project Server to SharePoint server. Is it possible?

Comment: what type of data you want to transfer and from which versions?

Comment: whatever there is in project server that all things I like to add in sharepoint and sharepoint version is 2010/2013

Answer (score 0):

Their is no define guideline to transfer data from Project server to SharePoint server.
Both products are from same family and build on Sp Foundation but have different functionality.

But if you want to move the documents from Project site to sharepoint then you can open the library in explorer and copy & paste to sharepoint site.

or use 3rd part tool, i am sure these tools will only transfer the list / libraries.

But if you are talking about the just site collections which are not using the Project server features in it, then you can move the site collection either DB attach or backup and restore...but make sure both side are on same patch level.